# AudioKit: AKSampler: Simplest way to add multiple samples

Tags: ios, audiokit

I understand so far that AKSampler was recently rewritten and [this GitHub project seems to be the defacto guide on the new AKSampler](https://github.com/AudioKit/SamplerDemo). What I can gather is a move toward SFZ format. I am new to the sampling world but in my application I only need a handful of samples recorded from my piano in order for it to work. As I have looked around with existing SFZ formats and samples, I do not need all of the complexity and features that SFZ provides.

I am currently using AKSampler with a single piano sample which works perfectly, however it gets a bit weird once I play anything too far from the original source, so I just want to fill in the gaps with a few other samples (I only need to play around an octave and a half with my current app).

I do see according to the [Docs](https://audiokit.io/docs/Classes/AKSampler.html#/c:@M@AudioKit@objc(cs)AKSampler(im)buildSimpleKeyMap) a couple methods `buildSimpleKeyMap()` and `buildKeyMap()` however there is no implementation currently.

Do I have any additional options? I know that EXS format has been deprecated, as well as SoundFont. Is the only way to map multiple samples to AKSampler currently using SFZ?

Thanks for all your help <3

Edit: [This readme on the AKSampler GitHub page](https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/blob/v4.2/Documentation/PreparingSampleSets.md) provides the breakdown for samples. I still only see SFZ being considered. If anyone else is lost with my question or needs a reference, this seems to be the best resource. If the current AKSampler only offers SFZ as the primary way to map multiple samples, so be it, however it does look very challenging, I'm really hoping there is some simple middle ground between only using a single sample for the AKSampler vs. a full bore SFZ file.

Edit 2: Getting a solution to this, will update as soon as possible, thanks for your patience!

Comment: in precise, if i understood you well you want to filter the background voice with your piano. Am i right?

Comment: Hi @HarjotSingh , not quite. What I'd like to do is instead of only having one sample tied to say "C4" for my AKSampler, I'd like to have 12 samples (one for each piano key, one octave) mapped to the AKSampler. The way that I see currently is to do via a SFZ file, however this is rather complex and I'd like to simply map from say C4-B5 a sample for each note. That way, when I play notes or chords with the AKSampler, it will not pitch stretch the notes, and instead play the actual recording.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I have provided a simple explainer and sample file in the AudioKit docs](https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/blob/v5-develop/Sources/AudioKit/Nodes/Playback/Samplers/PreparingSampleSets.md). Hope this helps new users of AudioKit!